# About enabling the virtualization capabilities of vmware within a virtual machine program

Tags: vmware

I'm going to install windows in centos using a virtual machine program.
So I checked [Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT/or AMD-V/RVI] in the virtual machine settings.
However, when you run the virtual machine, the error phrase is checked as shown in the picture below. If anyone knows, please reply.

[image]

[image]